# Import python module directory with "space" char

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I want to import a class named DataGenerator that is in the current file directory:

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/ssd/python_files/object_detection_2d_data_generator.py
```

I'm importing as follows:

```
from content.gdrive.My Drive.mrcnn_fire.ssd.python_files.object_detection_2d_data_generator import DataGenerator
```

It gives me the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-7d861f8abbeb>", line 4
    from content.gdrive.My Drive.mrcnn_fire.ssd.python_files.object_detection_2d_data_generator import DataGenerator
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Is your main script _also_ in `/content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/ssd/python_files`? If so, try importing without the path: `from object_detection_2d_data_generator import DataGenerator`

Comment: main script is not in same directory

Comment: The file name is the name of the module, but that means the file name has to obey Python's rules for module names: no spaces allowed. You import *modules*, not arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can try it this way:

```
# object_detection_2d_data_generator.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/ssd/python_files')

from object_detection_2d_data_generator import DataGenerator
```

Answer (score 2):

You can import it this way:

```py
DataGenerator = __import__("content/gdrive/My Drive/mrcnn_fire/ssd/python_files/object_detection_2d_data_generator/DataGenerator")
```

Comment: And you can do something like this too (if you module name that begins with number for example): ```solution = __import__( "foo bar", fromlist="ClassOrMethodName")```